# Which databases support efficient LIKE "%roger%"? (How can I make it faster?)

Tags: sql, database, performance

I am looking for a database that supports indexes like this:

```
select name from table where name Like "%roger%"
```

I have over a hundred thousand rows of text I need to search and SQL Server is taking too long.

Are there any databases or indices specifically designed for this query? (How can I make the above query faster?)

Comment: It's not the database vendor that's the problem here. The problem is that the `like` clause is computationally expensive, because you have to slide your search string over the entire candidate string to see if "roger" is anywhere in it.

Comment: Your problem is much more likely your server's configuration, database configuration, and understanding of what that sort of query is really asking. Changing databases will not be a solution.

Comment: Please ask X, not Y :-) I hope my edits were not out of line and lead to useful replies.

Comment: @pst Thanks that makes my question alot clearer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normal (b-tree) based indexes on **any** database can't work by design for a `LIKE` query that starts with `%`, as that forces a full scan. [Full-text indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) are the alternative for this type of query, or putting your searchable keywords into a different table and indexing that (may or may not be  a viable solution, depending on your situation).

Comment: How do full-text indexes differ?

Comment: @pst - by effectively doing the "putting your searchable keywords into a table" behind the scenes. There's more to it than that, but hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL b-tree indices with varchar_pattern_ops option will help LIKE searches, but I think (not 100% sure) only if left-anchored.

A full-text index/full-text search (different databases have different variants on the name) offers a different approach where a fast lookup based on the text contents (and in quite different ways for different databases) lets it find patterns. The results can also be more flexible too (with a degree of variants on the word being found).

Since you say you're on SQLServer, you should start at looking at what it offers you there at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx though actually, that's another place where I prefer PostgreSQL too :)

Answer (score 2):

Several other databases support the `LIKE` syntax, including MySQL. However I don't think you'll find a significant difference in speed.

Try adding a FULLTEXT index to the column in question (and using FULLTEXT MATCH/AGAINST)*, or consider alternate searching solutions like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

*** Note that FULLTEXT MATCH/AGAINST while fast, has some limitations that you might not want, like minimum character number, limited/no support for wildcards.

Comment: an index actually won't help due to the type of query being done here.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to optimize queries with

```
like 'foo%'
```

(where the search is anchored at the beginning) using standard indexes.

Your best bet for the case it seems you're asking about is to create a full-text index for your column.  Most popular databases support this, but the syntax and implementation varies.